# Why the same design matrix for GAM and LM lead to different results?

Tags: linear, generalized-additive-model

I am trying to use `loess` basis expansion on a toy data set. Why the same design matrix for GAM and LM lead to different results?

```
> library(gam)
> fit1=lm(mpg~lo(wt),data=mtcars)
> fit2=gam(mpg~lo(wt),data=mtcars)
> all(model.matrix(fit1)==model.matrix(fit2))
[1] TRUE
> anova(fit1,fit2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: mpg ~ lo(wt)
Model 2: mpg ~ lo(wt)
  Res.Df    RSS  Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)   
1   30.0 278.32                                 
2   26.6 177.47 3.4    100.86 4.4462 0.009422 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: The algorithms are quite different; the GAM backfitting involves weights being applied in an IRLS setting, whilst there are clearly no weights in the LM version. Whilst I don't recall all the details, I didn't think LOESS could be represented in a simple basis function form like this, but I may well be misremembering all of this; I don't recall ever using `gam::gam()`, preferring instead `mgcv::gam()`